# JMS exception when try to connect new JMS queue

Tags: jms-topic

when I try to migrate JMS queue to new server , I am getting below error messages.
When I connect with old JMS queue its working fine , so code looks good .

[#|2023-07-12T12:37:54.636+0100|WARNING|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.err|_ThreadID=16;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-1;_RequestID=b8f0dcba-bd88-4b78-bc71-aadd01f84e38;|
com.sun.messaging.jms.JMSException: [C4098]: Unknown broker service: jms
at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.PortMapperClient.getPortForService(PortMapperClient.java:109)
at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.protocol.tcp.TCPConnectionHandler.(TCPConnectionHandler.java:168)
at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.protocol.tcp.TCPStreamHandler.openConnection(TCPStreamHandler.java:135)
at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ConnectionInitiator.createConnection(ConnectionInitiator.java:778)
at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ConnectionInitiator.createConnectionNew(ConnectionInitiator.java:254)
at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ConnectionInitiator.createConnection(ConnectionInitiator.java:208)
at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ConnectionInitiator.createConnection(ConnectionInitiator.java:158)
at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ProtocolHandler.init(ProtocolHandler.java:836)
at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ProtocolHandler.(ProtocolHandler.java:1528)
at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ConnectionImpl.openConnection(ConnectionImpl.java:2363)
at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ConnectionImpl.init(ConnectionImpl.java:1044)
at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:430)
at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.UnifiedConnectionImpl.(UnifiedConnectionImpl.java:60)
at com.sun.messaging.BasicConnectionFactory.createConnection(BasicConnectionFactory.java:147)
at com.

when try to connect JMS queue in new server , which created newly as part of migration

Comment: resolved this issue  by deleting  'lock' file under C:\Software\glassfish\domains\{yourdomain-name}\imq\instances\imqbroker\  . Existing lock file contains old server name , so broker was not starting . Delete and restart glassfish solved the problem.